# I dont remember my wallet address it's been a year and half since I didn't withdraw

Tags: wallet, address, withdrawal

1. 

Withdrawal I forgotten my wallet address how to discover it

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean? Bitcoin Addresses are derived from public keys which are derived a private key which mostly consists of 24 words. Have you forgotten your 24 word seed phrases? If that is the case and you don't remember the 24 words, there is no way to brute force it. Unfortunately you can kiss those BTC goodbye.